# SOLR - How to pass parameters to dataimport

Tags: parameters, full-text-search, solr

How can i pass additional parameters to SOLR, while importing from database, using dataimport. Example:

I have sql query, smth like this: 

`Select * from documents where documentId > [myParameterHere]`

Can i somehow insert value to [myParameterHere]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do a partial import, take a look at [delta imports](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command).

Answer (score 6):

you can write this query:

`Select * from documents where documentId > ${dataimporter.request.myParameterHere}`

and post myParameterHere param in solr query url。